# How to implement differenet titles in marketplace and device

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-store

I created application and want that name of application in Windows Phone Marketplace will be another that on device.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The [App Manifest Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj247542(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_pagelist) will allow you to change the name of your app with how it appears when installed on a device. To set the name of the app in the marketplace you do so when you are submitting it through the Windows Phone Developer Dashboard.

Comment: It's not true, because WinPhone Store get title for marketplace from .XAP file. And name that you are submitting in dashboard never used.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I guess I misspoke. It appears that this must then be by design to avoid having apps display differently on your phone than they do in the store. Do you have an example of an app that you have seen do this?